# Using Google Apps script to get largest value on multible tabs of a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script

I am building a small script and one of the algorithm's task must be to return the largest value of a range of cells. The values are distributed along three tabs of the same spreadsheet. A mwe of the spreadsheet can be viewed at the link below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16WrsztYlOV7qDOMBqGYU8az26Bw9NoqdQ4Imk_hZM90/edit?usp=sharing

(for this example, the function must return 10 as an answer).

How can I accomplish that?

Any guidance is highly appreciated,

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A script is already in your example.  Just check the 'My Tools' menu to run it. It works.

```
function myMaxValue() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets=['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3'];
  var values=[];
  for(var i=0;i<sheets.length;i++)
  {
    var sht=ss.getSheetByName(sheets[i]);
    var rng=sht.getDataRange();
    var rngA=rng.getValues();
    for(var j=1;j<rngA.length;j++)
    {
      values.push(rngA[j][0]);
    }
  }
  values.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;});
  var max = values[values.length-1];
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('The max is ' + max); //Just checking to be sure it works
  return max;      
}
```